# Get BirthDay from GooglePlus sign in and Twitter SignIn

Tags: android, android-googleapiclient, android-twitter

I am using google plus and twitter sign in in my application. I need to access Birthday after particular sign in. How can I get birthday from twitter and googleplus sign in.

Answer (score 0):

`people.get()` for birthday:
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get

Twitter doesn't have an API for birthday.